# How to Merge rows data From DataTable in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

How to Merge rows data From DataTable in C#?

[image]

Comment: Post some code and show your efforts.

Comment: Hari i can post my code but i think it will not be helpfull in this case :( i just want to know how to merge data from two rows in datatable in c#?? i hve also attached image of the current datatable and the required datatable :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is a good use case for the [LINQ Group clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx). You can start with something like this:

```
var rowGroups = dataTable.Rows.GroupBy(row => 
    new {RecptNo = row["recpt_no"], Test = row["Test"]});
foreach(var group in rowGroups) 
{
  //Here "group" is a collection of rows with the same rectp_no and test. Process as required.
  //You could also check group.Key.RecptNo and group.Key.Test here if necessary.
}
```